# C# pre-build event doesn't appear to be expanding macro symbols?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, pre-build-event

I have a C# Project with the following line in the Pre-Build events:

copy "(RSSDK_DIR)\bin\win32\libpxccpp2c.dll" "($OutDir)" /Y

**RSSDK_DIR** is an environment variable and **$OutDir** is a recognized macro symbol.  I am trying to copy the given DLL from the first directory to the output directory.

When I build the project I get the error:

```
Error   1   The command "copy "(RSSDK_DIR)\bin\win32\libpxccpp2c.dll" "($OutDir)" /Y" exited with code 1.
```

I have done a similar task in C++ projects and it worked fine.  In addition, you could see the actual command *fully expanded* being run when the build event fires in the Output window.  In this case with my C# project, it doesn't appear to be expanding either the environment variable or the macro symbol.  I've read other SO posts on doing a file copy like this and my version appears to be the same as what I've seen.

How can I get this to work and are there any IDE settings or tools to help debug this?

Comment: Does my updated answer works for you???

Comment: @jmelosegui No it doesn't and I don't have time to put any more effort into this right now.  I did upvote your answer since I found it useful, but since I still have the problem I didn't mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, for specific macro variables the correct syntax is `$(OutDir)` instead of `($OutDir)`

<s>For environment variables you have to use the %variable% syntax, but because % is a reserved character in MSBuild you will need to replace it with %25.</s>

That does not work for me either, but good news is you could use the same syntax for environment variables though.

So you command should work like this

```
copy "$(RSSDK_DIR)\bin\win32\libpxccpp2c.dll" "$(OutDir)" /Y
```

Notice that inside visual studio `$(OutDir)` is  a virtual path and depending on what you are trying to do, you should consider using `$(TargetDir)` instead.

Comment: Thanks but I did see the MSDN article on that issue (%25 instead of %) and it didn't work.